# Nvidia Prime - Adaptive GPU switching?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, battery, intel, nvidia-optimus

I am new to using Ubuntu on a laptop (and thus am learning how to do all the configurations necessary for power management - which can be forgotten when using a desktop).

I have Nvidia Prime installed and have the Nvidia x server set to adaptive. However under the prime profile it says that the Nvidia GPU is selected always (even when I am doing nothing but showing my desktop wallpaper). So I switched to Intel GPU and then went to look at the Nvidia X server and all the options (e.g. adaptive) can not be found.

How do I get my computer to switch GPUs so I can have decent battery life.

I have a dell XPS 15 with a whopping 97 wH battery... and 3 hours hours of battery life on Ubuntu even with TLP.

Please help

Comment: You can run on Intel unless you play a game.

Answer (score 1):

I see only one "Adaptive" setting in Nvidia X Server Settings. It is in PowerMizer. This setting is not about switching adapters.

There is no way to automatically switch on Nvidia adapter with proprietary drivers in Linux systems yet.

You can set it per application using `bumblebee` project. But it does not seem to work well on new Ubuntu releases.

Comment: So if I use bumblebee instead I can say "if using application X use NVIDIA else use native Intel"? It drives me nuts that they don't support Ubuntu

Comment: @SumNeuron Do not use bumblebee. Learn to live with the reboot to change graphics. Unless you have an urge to play games each time you use the computer you can switch it to Intel and use that permanently.It's more than enough for all usual tasks including HD and 4K media but it'll struggle with modern 3D demanding games (at this point you switch to Nvidia).

Comment: @MichaelBay I got this laptop to use the GPU for computation, will switching to Intel prevent me of sending data to the NVIDIA GTX for computation?

Comment: @SumNeuron If you were using the Nvidia as well in Windows then performance and battery life should be similar. If, OTOH, you weren't but now with Ubuntu you're using it for computation (yes, required for CUDA) then a much shorter battery life should be expected. In the end what you reported is a non issue. Just use the graphics you need for any given task, select and reboot. Unlike in Windows, hybrid graphics aren't switched automatically in the same session.

Comment: @MichaelBay no, I removed Windows immediately